# Migration from SharePoint Foundation 2010 to SharePoint Server 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, migration

Which way is better in this case - Migration from SharePoint Foundation 2010 to SharePoint Server 2013?

1. SP Foundation 2010 --> SP Foundation 2013 --> SP Server 2013
2. SP Foundation 2010 --> SP Server 2013

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly upgrade to SP server 2013.

Also check:

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262483(v=office.15).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262483%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Comment: But then both of enviroments won't be the same, is it ok?

Comment: Do you mean "both of physical boxes" with "both of environment"? I am sorry i am not able to get your point.

Comment: New Farm will be not the same enviroment - more services in Sever version and so on?

Comment: Yes new farm will be new environment. Your whole content will be migrated to the new environment.